# Yammer ios app's uri scheme for opening a user profile

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, yammer, uri-scheme

I am currently integrating our cordova app with social networking apps such as twitter, linkedin and yammer. The first two apps provide uri scheme in directly opening the user's profile. E.g. twitter://user?screen_name=SREEN_NAME and linkedin://profile/PROFILE_ID respectively.

Now, I am trying to figure out for yammer. There doesn't seem to have much information in the internet. I managed to download the IPA file and extract the info.plist file. There, it shows yammer:// and it does open the ios app. I played around with the combination for opening a profile but did not have much luck. I am wondering if anyone had figured it out already. Would love if there's  a yammer developer around here.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at the moment we don't support a way to do this

Comment: Thank you, @peter! I am just wondering. Are you part of the development team of yammer's ios app?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in a xamarin.forms app in both iOS and Android environment using Jordan Hewitt's example here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48089/how-to-open-other-apps-from-xamarin-forms

The URI schema would be defined in Xamarin.forms in MainPage.xaml.cs as:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.OpenUri(new Uri("yammer://threads"));
```

For native iOS and Android the schema would be same: "yammer://threads"

Hope this helps.